# Ubuntu Server Install

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, server, bash

The Ubuntu ISO file is extracted to an USB which is booted first. I get this purple screen with blinking cursor on top left corner after i select INSTALL UBUNTU SERVER. What is the fix for this?

The link to he Picture :

[image]

Comment: Screenshot will help.

Comment: Do you _extract to_ or _burn_ ? Please add some screen shot.

Comment: @TonyLancer I have put the link

Comment: @George I extracted using linux live usb creator

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu Server (name of the iso file) did you download? Did you check that the download was good with *md5sum*? Which tool did you use to create the USB boot drive? Can you test how it works in another computer.

Comment: @sudodus The name of the Iso file is ubuntu-16.04.1-server-i386. The tool i used to create the usb boot drive was Linux Live USB creator. I was able to install in another computer but not in my PC.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with the graphics. You can try with the following hotkey combination: ctrl+alt+F2 ... ctrl+alt+F7. I think there should be a log output on ctrl+alt+F4, that might have some valuable information. (The installer is running in ctrl+alt+F1.)

Comment: Is your system 64bit or 32bit, be sure you downloaded the right one.

Comment: @George it is 32bit and i have downloaded the correct file.

Comment: @sudodus this computer doesnt have graphic card is that why this is happening is graphic card necessary can i bypass that ?

Comment: It is not necessary with a separate graphics card, if there is a grapics chip on the motherboard. There can be different chips. Can you find out what chips it is (brand name and model)? The server installer runs in text mode, and it will usually work. Can you find any information after pressing the hotkey combination: *ctrl+alt+F4* ?

Comment: @sudodus the graphic chip is Mobile Intel (R) 965 Express Chipset Family.

Comment: I don't know that particular chip, but there are people who know better than I at the Ubuntu Forums. I suggest that you start a thread at the server forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=339. Start by telling as much as possible about the computer and which version of Ubuntu Server you try to install.